# How to add "arr[i]" in a for loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop

How to add "arr[i].length" in my FOR LOOP? arr[0].length works fine, but "i" gives an error. I am trying to loop through a 2D arrays

```js
 function infiniteLoop(arr) {
   var answer;
   for (let i = 0; i < arr[i].length; i++) {
     answer =+1;
   }
   return answer;
 }


 document.write(infiniteLoop([
   [1, 2, 3],
   [4, 5, 6],
   [7, 8, 9]
 ]));
```

Comment: what length are you trying to compare to? this makes no sense

Answer (score 3):

You can't - you're asking it to look for the value of `i` before `i` actually exists. You have a two-dimensional array, and so need to use nested for-loops:

```
var answer = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  for(var j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
    answer += 1;
  }
}
```

P.S. You also need to start `answer` at `0`. You can't add the value of `1` to an `undefined` variable.

Answer (score 1):

You want to loop through the length of your array, then use another loop to go through the inner array elements.

```
 function infiniteLoop(arr) {
   var answer;
   for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
     for (let j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
       // SOME CODE
     }
   }
   return answer;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You actually need to handle this using two loops as one will need to iterate through your actual array that was passed in `arr` and then another could iterate through the elements of the inner array :

```
function infiniteLoop(arr) {
   var answer = 0;
   // Iterate through your array of arrays ([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]], etc.)
   for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
       // Now go through each individual array (i.e. [1,2,3], etc.)
       for (let j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
            answer += 1;
       }
   }
   return answer;
}
```

There are likely shorter, non-loop alternatives if you want to count the number of elements within your array, but this should work for what you need to do.

Answer (score 0):

```
 function array2dStuff(a)
{
    var n = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
    {
        for (var j = 0; j < a[i].length; j++)
        {
            //n += a[i][j];    // for sum of numbers
            n++;               // for number of elements
        }
    }
    return n;
}
```